# Will ARC works for .mm file

Tags: ios, automatic-ref-counting, avaudioplayer, avaudiorecorder

I am using AVAudioRecorder and AVAudioPlayer in my .mm class to record and play .wav file (I have to record maximum 90 minutes continually at a time.). But I found while profiling memory usage is never coming back even after I nullify my player and record object.

It would be nice if anybody can suggest some work around.

Comment: there is nothing to fix unless your app crashed due to low memory or instruments tell you there _is_ memory leak

Comment: @Brayan thanks for your comment but My application crashed due to memory leak... Yeah there is no leak

Comment: there is no connection with ARC and .mm file

Answer (score 0):

Short answer, yes. If there's a leak, it's probably not your fault, unless you have a retain cycle or un-deactivated timer.

You can try sending a memory warning manually and see if the memory goes down.

Answer (score 0):

Yes it will. For the issue with the leaks, use Xcode's native instruments such as Leaks to see where your problems lye.

Comment: DO NOT enable NSZombie if you want to debug memory leak.

Comment: @BryanChen My bad I was mistaken, edited OP. Thank you.